# Type Mismatch when trying to access CodeModule of a form component

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I have following code in a form module:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim oFormComp    As VBComponent
Dim oModule      As VBComponent

  Set oFormComp = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Me.Name)
  Set oModule = oFormComp.CodeModule    'Type Mismatch err 13
End Sub
```

The last line gives me the type mismatch error. I have tried to do exactly what I have seen others do in relevant posts. What am I missing?
I have referenced the extensibility library, and set the trust settings for macro's wide open.

Comment: Try `Dim oModule      As CodeModule`.

Comment: arggggh overlooked that one for hours.... thanks!!